# Oracle Hash-Function

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table that is being populated from a Materialized view.

I'm looking for a way to identify & update only records that have values that have changed.
I have thought about using Oracle's standard hash function to check data consistency but, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this would just tell me "something" changed, not "what changed".

Is there a "best" way to do this type of comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) Statement. This should serve you well.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i was looking for.